# List of all Object's fields which are not refer anywhere in System

Tags: apex, metadata

We have a requirement where we need to clear each fields which are just lying in the system and not used any where to make environments more cleaner, Is there any way to do this. I used eclipse earlier for reverse process where we chose any field and can find its reference.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If you try deleting an individual object it will tell you all the references.

Comment: I have only used eclipse so far, but i have to go each and every field and put that in search bar to find its reference. Second way i tried is try deleting them if that is refer anywhere salesforce don't allow to delete. But this is very long way. I am looking for any alternate way anyone has tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but Salesforce does offer an "Optimizer" feature, which examines your org, and reports possible improvements in a few areas. One of those areas is field usage, allowing you to see fields which have not been populated in about 6 months.

A few categories reported by a Optimizer report generated a few months ago:

- Field Limits per Object
- Field Usage per Object
- Field Usage per Page Layout

[Offical Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=optimizer_kick_off.htm&type=5).